# boundary regularity

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m} $ be an open and bounded domain. We say that $U$ is  $C^{2}$ if for each $z \in \partial U$, there exists $r>0$  and a  $C^{2}$ function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{m-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (upon relabeling and reorienting the coordinates axes if necessary) such that
\begin{align*}
 U \cap B(z,r ) = \{ x \in B(z,r): x_m > \phi( x_1, \ldots ,x_{m-1} ) \}  
.\end{align*}

I want to show that $\partial D$ can be represented as a graph of $\phi$ locally.
If we consider the ball $B((z_1, ... ,z_{m-1}),r)$, it is not necessarily the case that its image under $\phi$ is a subset of $\partial D$.

How can I show that there exists $r'< r$ such that $\phi (B((z_1, ... ,z_{m-1}),r')) = \partial U \cap B(z,r)$. There will be a local parametrization $(x_1, ... , \phi(x_1, ... ,x_{m-1}))$ of the boundary curve.

Denote $x':=(x_1, ... ,x_{m-1})$. I guess we can use the implicit function theorem to prove it. Consider the function $F(x',x_m)= \phi(x')-x_m$, which is a $C^2$ function. Then, there exists a open neighbourhood $B(z',r')$ and a unique $g \in C^1(B(z',r'))$ such that $0=F(z', g(z')) = \phi(z')-g(z') =0$. By the uniqueness of $G$, $\phi$ must agree with $g$ on $B(z',r')$.

Now $\phi(B(z',r')) \subset \partial D$ and we are done.